# How to force the object's children to be a certain interface or to extends from this interface?

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

I would like to force the object's children to be a certain interface or to extends from this interface.
For example:

```
export interface Configuration {
  pages: {
    home: IHome;
    about: IAbout; // I want IAbout will have to extends IPage
    contact: IPage;
  };
}
interface IPage {
  displayName: string;
}

interface IHome extends IPage {
  slider: any; // property that only Home has
}

interface IAbout { // How to force this interface to extends IPage like IHome interface
  map: any; // property that only About has
}
```

How can i force `IAbout` to `extends IPage`?
I know the method `[pageName: string]: IPage`,
but it won't force `IPage` to `extends IPage`.
Is there a way to enforce that the values will inherit from `IPage`?

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking.  What do you mean that `Home` doesn't extend `Page`?   Can you include some code that shows what you'd like to see compile without errors and what you'd like to see compile with errors?

Comment: You gotta be more clear, `Home` already extends `Page` cause you wrote `interface Home extends Page`. What else do you need? As a side note, name your interfaces `IPage`, `IHome`, etc. to differentiate from class types. Also, since `Home` extends from `Page`, there is no need to put `displayName` in both. Take it out from `Home`. Are there other properties in these interfaces, your code seems to be too simplified. paste in more and provide more explanation.

Comment: I've added a more specific example and corrected your suggestions @codeepic

Comment: I've added a more specific example @jcalz

Comment: Ok, it's a little bit clearer but this question is still confusing: `How can i force IPage to extends IPage?
I know the method [pageName: string]: IPage, but it won't force IPage to extends IPage.` --> interface can't extend itself. If you want to force `IAbout` to extend `IPage` just write `IAbout extends IPage` like you did for `IHome`. Seriously dude, you need to be very clear with your questions on SO or they get downvoted and removed real quick.

Comment: I would urge you to include some code that explicitly shows some intended uses of your types and especially some uses you'd like to prevent.  Right now you are saying "extends" but perhaps you mean something else.

Comment: Sorry it was a mistake, I corrected it. i know that i can just write extends IPage next IAbout but i want to force it by declaring pages object as IPage values container only @codeepic

Comment: I think I know where you're going with this. You could write it like `pages: {[pageName: string]: IPage};` So you basically state that any page should be of type or subtype `IPage`. Check Liskov substitution principle --> SOLID principles for more explanation. The problem is that unless you use `Configuration` or `IHome`, `IAbout` interfaces somehere in your code, you won't get any transpilation errors. But if you implement these interfaces and you haven't extended e.g `IHome` with `IPage` you should get some errors.

Comment: OK thank you!
The solution to the question is to put in addition to all values the definition: ```[pageName: string]: IPage```
And so everyone will have to ```extends IPage```

Comment: I checked again and there is a problem, everything seems normal and ```[pageName: string]: IPage``` forces everyone to ```extends IPage```, but once you try to create a configuration object, there is an error that the slider does not exist at home because it is IPage rather than IHome.
Do you know why this happens? @codeepic

Comment: @Adi1231234 have a look here https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-kbfp9s - no errors - does your code looks similar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you meant that each nested object would be both the given interface and the IPage interface.

You can use intersection with IPage and mapped object with computed keys.

```js
type ChildrenWithIPage<T extends object> = {
  [key in keyof T]: T[key] & IPage;
};

export interface Configuration {
  pages: ChildrenWithIPage<{
    home: IHome;
    about: IAbout;
    contact: IPage;
  }>;
}
interface IPage {
  displayName: string;
}

interface IHome {
  slider: any;
}

interface IAbout {
  map: any;
}
```

Using `[key in keyof T]` will iterate over all the keys of T, `T[key]` will return the value in property `key`, and `& IPage` will create an intersection, which acts very similiar to interface's inheritance